# Vaadin 14: Is it possible to define layout in @Route with a method?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

When using `@Route`, it is possible to define a `RouterLayout` with the attribute `layout`. However, I  would like to define a global default layout. Is it possible to define the layout in a method, or configure a different default than `<body>` somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a parent layout for any RouterLayout with the `@ParentLayout` annotation:

```
@ParentLayout(MyParentLayout.class)
public class MyRouterLayout extends Div implements RouterLayout  {
...
```

Here `MyRouterLayout` will be shown inside `MyParentLayout`, not `<body>`.